# `comprehensive.sty' not found

Tags: packages, tlmgr

I was trying to include the comprehensive.sty package(https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) in my tex code with

```
\usepackage{comprehensive}
```

But it gives an error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `comprehensive.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

I've already used `tlmgr` to check that I do have `comprehensive` installed in my TeXlive 2021. What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: There is no `comprehensive.sty`. The TeX Live package called `comprehensive` provides a PDF document where a big list of symbols can be examined.

Comment: @egreg Thank you! I get it